# Split plot with factorial design vs three way ANOVA

Tags: anova, experiment-design, split-plot

I have three site temperature types: cold, medium, and hot. This is a fixed effect - I am specifically am testing if temperature affects my response variable. I believe temperature type is my 'block'.

I will have three sites for each temperature type. I think site is a random effect. Within each site, I will have a factorial design, where two other fixed factors, A and B, are crossed.

I am interested in the interaction of all three fixed effect (tempxAxB).

From reading my stats book, I think this is a split plot design, but my stats book does not have information about factorial design (the cross of A and B) within blocks. **Is what I just described a split plot design or a three way ANOVA?** And if it is a funky split plot, could someone point me to an ANOVA table (how to calculate sum of squares) with a similar set up?

Here is a schematic of the setup:

[image: Set up]

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion your design more strongly resembles a **nested design**. `Individuals` are nested within the `sites`. Hence, I would advise to either treat `site` simply as a fixed effect covariate (due to the small number of levels) or use some sort of [hierarchical modeling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_linear_modeling) (could be difficult, again due to the low number of `site` levels).

The question of whether or not you have a split plot design is dependent on the smallest [experimental unit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Experimental_unit). If this would indeed be `site` you would have a split-plot (or repeated-measures) design, as your experimental units would undergo different treatments. However, from your description it sounds like you sample experimental units within each `site` making those the smallest experimental unit. As long as experimental units are not assigned to more than one condition, it is not a split-plot design. Rather, you seem to have a two-level multilevel model (e.g., sampling students within classes).